# OK to use underscore for autosynthesized properties in block (strong reference cycle)

Tags: objective-c, memory, objective-c-blocks

Say I have something like this:

```
@interface Foo : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *name;

@end

@implementation Foo

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    _name = @"Me";
    NSArray *blackList = @[@"John", @"Malcolm", @"Jimmy"];
    [blackList enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        if ([obj isEqualToString:_name])  // Is _name just as bad as using self.name?
        {
            NSLog(@"You're on the blacklist!");
            *stop = YES;
        }
    }];
}

@end
```

The question is on this line: `if ([obj isEqualToString:_name])`

I know it's bad to refer to self inside a block, and you can get around it by using `__weak Foo *weakSelf = self` and then refer to `weakSelf` in the block.

```
__weak Foo *weakSelf = self;
[blackList enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    if ([obj isEqualToString:weakSelf.name])
    {
        NSLog(@"You're on the blacklist!");
        *stop = YES;
    }
}];
```

However, is this still bad if we don't explicitly write `self.name`, but write `_name`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is `_name` just as bad as using `self.name`?

Yes, it is. In fact, `self` reference is still there - the compiler inserts it for you.

> you can get around it by using `__weak Foo *weakSelf = self` and then refer to `weakSelf` in the block.

You can use the same trick here by referring to `weakSelf->_name`

Note: It is not necessary to use this trick with `enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:`, because the enumeration finishes and the block gets released in the scope of your method. A threat of retain cycle happens only when you put the block in a variable on the `self` object, while also referring to `self` from the block.

Comment: @doctordoder: But it should be noted that `enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:` does not cause a retain cycle at all. You can use `self.name` or `_name` without problems inside the block. The block retains self temporarily, and releases it when the enumeration is finished. There is no need for a weak reference here at all.

Comment: @MartinR Thanks for a great comment! I edited the answer to mention your point.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight The block doesn't necessarily have to be a variable on the `self` object, right?  Could be asynchronous code, which wouldn't necessarily create a permanent retain cycle, but certainly a retain cycle that could very easily extend the life of the object more than intended.  Or if the block is going to be a property of another object, which this object already has a strong reference to, etc.

Comment: @nhgrif Right - there are many scenarios that could lead to a retain cycle. That's unfortunate - I wish compilers could detect and eliminate retain cycles :-(

Comment: That note is quite interesting. Obvious, but not immediately. Thanks for putting in that as well.

Comment: @MartinR So is it if the block is called on `self` or any object that `self` has a strong reference to? When would it happen other than being called on `self`?

Answer (score 1):

There are two good options here, if I understand the question correctly.

Either create a `weakSelf` as you indicate, and reference name by one of two ways:

```
weakSelf.name
```

Or

```
weakSelf->_name
```

Or just create a weak reference to `name` and refer to that:

```
__weak __block NSString* weakName = name;
```

And refer to `weakName`.

<s>Using `_name` isn't technically quite as bad as `self.name`, as you'll only retain-cycle the string object rather than the entire class, but you're still creating a retain cycle, and you really shouldn't be doing this.</s>

Well I've been corrected and apparently `self` still is retained here, so it is exactly as bad as capturing `self` (it's identically the same thing).  There are still 3 good options for you here though.

Comment: Not strictly true – using an ivar inside a block reference like this implicitly captures `self`, just like referring to `self` explicitly would. The proposed solutions are still accurate, though.

Comment: *"so it is exactly as bad as capturing self"* : No, it is a *good* as capturing self, because there is no retain cycle here (see my comment to the other answer).

Comment: @MartinR In this specific instance there's no retain cycle, but the question seems to be about blocks in general, not this specific block.  The question clearly contains sample code.  But you're right in this specific instance, and it's worth understanding blocks well enough to know whether or not you're going to create a retain cycle that you need to worry about.

Comment: @nhgrif: Yes, my comment was meant only for this particular example.